# Recoding into a new categorical variable, where a category gets converted to NA

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, expss

I am currently trying to recode variables with an NA but I am having problems.

I am having trouble and my data looks like this for an income variable:

```
Income1
0
1
1
2
2
0
```

I wanted to remove the 0s and recode them into NAs. The 0s represent respondents who marked down 'choose not to answer'. I have tried this:

```
> Comm %>%
+   mutate(Income2 = case_when(Income1 = 0 ~ NA_real_,
+                              Income1 = 1 ~ 'Less than 50K'
+                              Income1 = 2 ~ 'More than 50K'))
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Income2 = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! `0` must be a vector with type <logical>.
Instead, it has type <double>.
```

I tried converting Income1 as a logical but for whatever reason it's not working. So I tried using the expss package (SPSS like package). I wanted to retain the 1s and 2s.

```
Comm$Income2 = recode(Comm$Income1, "No answer" = 0 ~ NA_real_, 
                          "Less Than 50K" = 1 ~ 1, 
                          "More Than 50K" = 2 ~ 2)
```

That did not work because:

```
Error in process_recodings(x, unlist(list(...), recursive = TRUE), make_empty_vec(x),  : 
  'recode' - labelled recodings should recode into single not-NA value but we have: 0 ~ NA
```

Thank you for reading, any advice would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for `recode` from `expss`. The error message said: " labelled recodings should recode into single **not-NA** value". So you need to remove the label from your recoding to `NA`. The reason for this is that label on NA (missing) value is not allowed both in SPSS and in expss. Code below works:

```
Comm$Income2 = recode(Comm$Income1, 0 ~ NA_real_, 
                      "Less Than 50K" = 1 ~ 1, 
                      "More Than 50K" = 2 ~ 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

first thing, you forgot to add a comma after 'Less than 50K' in your case statement. Using NA_real_ also creates an issue because it is used to represent missing integer values in numeric columns, but the mutate here tries to create a character-type column so NA_real_ wouldn't be the appropriate data type here.

I would suggest you use NA_character_ instead. Also, you may want to change the "=" sign to "==" as only one "=" sign is used for variable assignment but "==" is used to check equality, as R is probably reading the = sign as a variable assignment.

This should work now:

```
Comm %>%
  mutate(Income2 = case_when(Income1 == 0 ~ NA_character_,
                             Income1 == 1 ~ 'Less than 50K',
                             Income1 == 2 ~ 'More than 50K'))
```

Comment: Awesome! Had no idea about NA_character_ - thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your variable into *factor* ignoring 0; it will get converted into missing. Or use *subsetting* combined with `match`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Method 1

Comm |> 
  mutate(Income2 = factor(Income1, levels=1:2, labels=c("Less Than 50K", "More Than 50K")))

# Method 2
Comm |> 
  mutate(Income2 = c("Less Than 50K", "More Than 50K")[match(Income1, 1:2)])

  Income1       Income2
1       0          <NA>
2       1 Less Than 50K
3       1 Less Than 50K
4       2 More Than 50K
5       2 More Than 50K
6       0          <NA>
```

#### data

```
Comm = structure(list(Income1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                 class = "data.frame")
```